# set interval() not showing number one by one

Tags: jquery

Hello friend i tried to show number 1 to 4 one bye one with loop my code is

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        setInterval(function() {            
            var i = 1;
            for(i=0; i<=5; i++)
            {
                var dis = $('#fade');                   
                dis.html(i);                    
                i++;
            }           
        }, 2000);
    });    
</script>
```

but its showing result number and stop working plz help me 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to show the numbers from 1 to 4 I would suggest using setTimeout the following way:

```
var counter = 1;
$(function() {
  incrementCounter();
});

function incrementCounter() {
  $('#fade').html(counter);
  counter++;
  if (counter < 4) {
    setTimeout(incrementCounter, 2000);
  }
}
```

An alternative would be the following:

```
$(function() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#fade').html(counter);
    }, (i - 1) * 2000);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/eN2se/2/

You can't call all the `setInterval` functions at once, they get executed directly. 
**Update: use setTimeout**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var display = function(i) {
    $('#fade').html(i);
    if (i < 4) {
        setTimeout(function() {display(++i)}, 1000);
    }                    
  };
  display(1);
});
```

Comment: This will execute multiple interval functions concurrently and none of them will ever stop. I think you have at least to change `setInterval` to `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Sirko you are right, didn't even notice, bad habit of copy-paste !

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second `document ready` - it's totally redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I think the counter you want to achieve, can be done with this code (although I'm not sure I understood you correctly):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var counter = 1,
            max = 5;

        var timer = setInterval(function() {

           $('#fade').html( counter );

           counter += 1;     

           // stop after <max> iterations
           if ( number > max ) {
              window.clearInterval( timer );
           }

        }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var counter = 1;
        var timerId = -1;

        timerId = setInterval(function() {
           if(counter == 5) clearInterval(timerId);
           $('#fade').html( counter );

           counter += 1;     

        }, 2000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z5BMn/8/

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the following

```
$(function(){    
        setInterval(function() {
        for(i=0; i<=5; i++)
        {
            $('#fade').append(i);                  
        }       

    }, 2000);
    })​
```

Comment: Just noted you want 1-5 if you change the i=0 to i=1 that will loop 1-5 in a div :)

Answer (score 0):

using jasd's example I've added another line of code that will make it repeat.

```
var counter = 1;
$(function() {
  incrementCounter();
});

function incrementCounter() {
  $('#fade').html(counter);
  counter++;
  if (counter <= 5) {
    setTimeout(incrementCounter, 2000);
  }else{
      counter = 1;
      setTimeout(incrementCounter, 2000);
  }
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BMnvX/2/